# Why the useMemo is not working? Am I using it wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am just getting the hang of useMemo and useCallback and playing around to see how things are working. What I want to do in this scenario is not to render the Child whenever the parent is sending the same object.

Here is my Parent component:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const handleOnClick = e => {
    setValue(value + 1);
  };

  const myObject = useMemo(() => {
    return { value: value - value };
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I am a parent</h1>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>
        Click on Me
      </button>
      <Child object={myObject} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

And here is my Child which is re-rendering on each click although the content of "myObject" is the same. (I know the reference changes each time but my understanding is that's what useMemo does)

```
const Child = ({ object }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I am child</h1>
      <p>Object is {JSON.stringify(object)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Child);
```

[Here is the Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-grass-zgki0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Please let me know what am I doing wrong and what's the solution for this case?

Comment: When do you want it to recompute the memoization? By providing a dependency array of `[value]` you've told it to recompute any time value changes, so that's what it's doing.

Comment: `0 - 0 = 0`, `1 - 1 = 0`, `2 - 2 = 0`, `value - value = 0`. Why do you expect the value to ever not be `0`?

Comment: @NicholasTower I want it to recompute each time the value changes. I don't want my component to re-render if the result of the computation is the same.

Comment: @JMadelaine for the sake of testing, and using a real dependency but getting the same result each time, I did the value - value to get the same result even though the value changes. My expectation is when the result of the computation is the same the component does'nt re-render

Comment: `each time the value changes` That's what it's doing, as long as by "value" you mean the variable on line 2. Every time that variable change, the memoization is recomputed, and thus a new object is created, and thus the child rerenders.`My expectation is when the result of the computation is the same the component does'nt re-render` It's not the same though. It's a brand new object, which would fail a `===` with the previous object. The properties of the object are never checked. Only the things in the dependency array are checked.

Comment: So change the dependecy.. if the dependecy change it recomputes

Comment: @NicholasTower Ok, very clear answer thanks. So the useMemo as you mentioned doesn't care about the result of the computation, it only cares about when to run it. So what is the solution for my scenario? I don't want the Child to re-render when the result of my computation is the same.

Comment: Do the computation outside of useMemo and pass its result (and only it's result) into useMemo's dependency array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency array is what controls when the memoization breaks. If anything in that array has changed, then the memoization runs again. React only checks that array though, not the finished product.

Right now you're telling it to recompute any time `value` changes. You can provide something else to the array if `value` is not what you want. Your example of `value - value` doesn't make much sense since it will never change, so let me replace it which will change half of the time:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const handleOnClick = e => {
    setValue(value + 1);
  };

  const halfValue = Math.round(value / 2);
  const myObject = useMemo(() => {
    return { halfValue: halfValue };
  }, [halfValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I am a parent</h1>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>
        Click on Me
      </button>
      <Child object={myObject} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now the memoization will be recomputed on every other click.